# One Parameter family of soultions for this Riccati's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a one parameter family of solutions of the Riccati's equation
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac4{x^2}-\frac{y}{x}+y^2$$

So I am trying to follow  a sort of template I was given:

Let $y=y_1+u$, where $y_1$ is a particular solution of the DE.
Then,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{du}{dx}$$

Plugging into DE and we get,
$$\frac{dy_1}{dx}+\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac4{x^2}-\frac{y_1}{x}-\frac{u}{x}+y_1^2+2uy_1+u^2$$

Since $y_1$ is a particular solution,
$$\frac{dy_1}{dx}=-\frac4{x^2}-\frac{y_1}{x}+y_1^2$$

Plugging in and canceling we get,
$$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{u}{x}+2uy_1+u^2 \implies$$
$$\frac{du}{du}-u(\frac1x-2y_1)=u^2$$
Which is now a Bernoulli's Equation.

**Question:**

How can I complete this problem and find my 1-parameter family of solutions? Maybe I am thinking of this wrong, but I cannot do a Bernoulli's equation if $y_1$ is still there right? I believe I need to solve for $y_1$ but I am not sure how to.

Thank You for the help.

Comment: $y_1=2/x$ is a  particular solution of that Ricatti 's equation just check it $(y_1=-\frac 2x$ is also another solution)

Comment: @Isham Is this soley through observation?

Comment: well I tried $y_1=\frac ax$ then got the double value for a ($a= \pm 2$)...now you can use your trick and reduce the equation into Bernouilli's equation and get a general solution

Comment: @Isham Is there a way to show this, or from the problem do you get the feeling it should be from observation?

Comment: I guess one can solve that equation easily but if you wanna use your trick you need a particular solution and for this observation helps a lot

Comment: Sometimes I wonder where that misspelling of Riccati's surname comes from, because it appears to be rather common.

Answer (score 1):

The method that you use to solve a Riccati's equation is the simplest, insofar one know a particular solution.

In academic exercises the most likely one can guess a particular solution by inspection and check that the guess is fine. Then, the solving is easy. This is the case in the present exercise with the particular solution $y_1=\frac{2}{x}$ .

When one cannot find a particular solution, the method is as follows.

The Riccati's ODE is a non-linear ODE. It is well-known that a non-linear ODE is generally more difficult to solve that a linear ODE, even if the order of linear ODE is higher that the order of the non-linear ODE. That is why there is an advantage to transform the first order non-linear ODE into a second order linear ODE.

The method to transform a Riccati's ODE into a second order linear ODE is very simple. The general form of the Riccati's ODE is :
$$y'(x)=P(x)+Q(x)y(x)+R(x)(y(x))^2$$
The change of function :
$$y(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{R(x)f(x)}$$
leads to a linear second order ODE.

Let try this method with the equation :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac4{x^2}-\frac{y}{x}+y^2$$
We see that $R(x)=1$, so the change of function is :
$$y(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
$$y'=-\frac{f''}{f}+\frac{f'^2}{f^2}=-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{f'}{xf}+\frac{f'^2}{f^2}$$
$$x^2f''+xf'-4f=0$$
It is easy to solve the linear second order ODE :
$$f=c_1x^2+c_2\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$f'=2c_1x-2c_2\frac{1}{x^3}$$
$$y=-\frac{2c_1x-2c_2\frac{1}{x^3}}{c_1x^2+c_2\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{2(-c_1x^4+c_2)}{x(c_1x^4+c_2)}$$
$$\begin{cases}
y=\frac{2(-x^4+C)}{x(x^4+C)}\quad\text{with}\quad c_1\neq 0.\\
y=\frac{2}{x}\quad\text{with}\quad c_1=0.\\
y=-\frac{2}{x}\quad\text{with}\quad c_2=0.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

hint: With $$y(x)=\frac{v(x)}{x}$$ we get
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{v(x)^2-4}{x}$$ so we obtain
$$\frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}}{v(x)^2-4}=\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are doing here my apologies.

Comment: @NickPavini It means that the DE now is separable $\frac{dv}{v^2-4}=\frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: @Cesareo and we let $y=\frac{v(x)}{x}$ why?

Comment: @NickPavini First we solve for $v(x)$ and then we have $y = \frac{v(x)}{x}$ So we recover the initial variable transformation.